# Test closure of an extension function in Kotlin

Tags: testing, kotlin, junit, kotlin-coroutines

Suppose we have the following code:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
fun ProducerScope<DownloadableDataDto<out User>>.findInteresting(input: ReceiveChannel<DownloadableDataDto<out User>>,
                                                                 communitiesCount: Int,
                                                                 userCountMap: MutableMap<User, Int> = ConcurrentHashMap()) = createProducer(input) {
    if (userCountMap.compute(it.data!!) { _, value ->
                if (value == null) 1 else value + 1
            } == communitiesCount) send(it)
}
```

This code checks if a user is a part of all of the `communitiesCount` communities. But this logic is enclosed inside a `createChannel()` higher order function, which I would not want to test at the moment. Is there a way to test only the internals? I assume I could probably extract that to a separate function as well, right?

And if I do it that way, let's say we have this instead:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
fun ProducerScope<DownloadableDataDto<out User>>.findInteresting(input: ReceiveChannel<DownloadableDataDto<out User>>,
                                                                 communitiesCount: Int,
                                                                 userCountMap: MutableMap<User, Int> = ConcurrentHashMap()) = createProducer(input) {
    sendIfInteresting(it, communitiesCount, userCountMap)
}

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
private suspend fun ProducerScope<DownloadableDataDto<out User>>.sendIfInteresting(userDto: DownloadableDataDto<out User>,
                                                                                   communitiesCount: Int,
                                                                                   userCountMap: MutableMap<User, Int>) {
    if (userCountMap.compute(userDto.data!!) { _, value ->
                if (value == null) 1 else value + 1
            } == communitiesCount) send(userDto)
}
```

How would I mock the `send(userDto)` call? I can mock the `ProducerScope` object, but how would I call the real `sendIfInteresting()` method?

Comment: Using a spy. Did you consider using a mocking library?

Comment: @m0skit0 yes, the question was about how I would use a library. So you mean I would create an object that has all the real methods and only stub the `send()`, right?

Comment: Yes, however each mocking library is different, so you should really specify which one you're using for a more detailed help.